# Shopware 6: Disable cookie consent

Tags: shopware

How can disable the cookie consent tool?

I know the is no option (Shopware issue [NEXT-9096](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-9096))

You have to disable it in the template.
I tried storefront/layout/cookie/cookie-permission.html.twig but that's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable the cookie notification create a new file in your plugin `YourPlugin/src/Resources/views/storefront/layout/cookie/cookie-permission.html.twig` with the content:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/cookie/cookie-permission.html.twig' %}

{% block layout_cookie_permission_inner %}
{% endblock %}
```

This will disable the `layout_cookie_permission_inner` block containing the cookie notification.

Comment: I skipped `sw_extends` because I thought it will overwrite the whole file. With `sw_extends` it works like expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this without changing template.

Use option in:
Settings > Basic information > Security and Privacy > Use Default Cookie Notification
"You can deactivate the default cookie notification if you are using a third party solution."